# JavaScript Write Text To Image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I Have a issue about write text to image. I need loop the image. But i get some issue. When i do it , Last image showing and the images size is small. Do anyone help me ?

```js
var div=document.getElementById("locations");
var canvas;

window.onload = function(){
    for(var i=0;i<10;i++){
        canvas=document.createElement("canvas");
        canvas.style.width="75px";
        canvas.style.height="75px"

        var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
        var imageObj = new Image();
        imageObj.onload = function(){
            context.drawImage(imageObj, 0, 0);
            context.font = "17px Calibri";
            context.fillText(i, 30, 36);
        };
        imageObj.src = "image.png"; 
        div.appendChild(canvas);
    };
}
```

```html
<div id="locations"></div>
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="75" height="75"></canvas>
```

Result Image

[image: Result Image]

Comment: imageObj.onload = function(){
   context.drawImage(imageObj, 0, 0);
   context.font = "17px Calibri";
   context.fillText(i, 30, 36);
   canvas.style.width=imageObj.width+"px";
   canvas.style.height=imageObj.height+"px"
  };

Comment: It doesn't working. I get some issue again..

Answer (score 0):

Use canvas.height and width values instead of CSS style. CSS style values applied after canvas drawn.

```js
var div=document.getElementById("locations");
var canvas;

window.onload = function(){
    for(var i=0;i<10;i++){
        canvas=document.createElement("canvas");
        canvas.width=75;
        canvas.height=75;

        var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
        var imageObj = new Image();
        imageObj.onload = function(){
            context.drawImage(imageObj, 0, 0);
            context.font = "17px Calibri";
            context.fillText(i, 30, 36);
        };
        imageObj.src = "http://placehold.it/350x150"; 
        div.appendChild(canvas);
    };
}
```

```html
<div id="locations"></div>
```